# struts 2 jsp radio button action

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, html-table, struts2, radio-button

I have a list with objects and jsp table is filled using those objects. I want to add a radio button column to that table and when I click one radio button I want to load that object into relevant text fields for update process. How can I do this?

This is my jsp code for table:

```
<table class="tldFromContent" border="1" width="800px">

    <tr class="tblMenuColorMsg" height="25px">
        <td>Select</td>
        <td><strong>Description</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <%
        int j = 0;
    %>
    <s:iterator value="pcinitiladataList">
        <tr >
            <td><input type="radio" id="selectedCar1" name="selectedCar" value="${decrp}"  >Edit</td>
                <td align="right"><s:property
                        value="decrp" /></td>                                                   
        </tr>
        <%j++;%>
    </s:iterator>
</table>
```

What I want to do is when I click a radio button in table, relevant data in that raw should load in to the text fields and date time pickers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use Ajax update field tag from the AjaxWebparts library
Here is the link and the example

http://ajaxtags.sourceforge.net/usage.html

hope this helps :)

Comment: I have use a hidden variable to do it. That problem is fixed. Thanks.